# Unable to connect to Wireless Ad-hoc networks in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I'm not able to setup Ad-hoc network in ubuntu. I came to know that setting up a ad-hoc network is different from setting up a wireless hotspot.

- After I followed the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Adhoc), my essid changes everytime I do it. I'm not able to setup a specific essid name for my wifi card.
- I also tried [this](http://thangamaniarun.wordpress.com/2012/12/24/adhoc-network-on-ubuntu-12-0412-10-how-to/) but in vain.

I tried to make sure that essids are same on two individual PCs (running Ubuntu Linux 10.04 and 12.04) described here.

I still cannot ping one system from the other.

Did anyone ever try connecting two systems over Wi-Fi in ad-hoc mode (in Ubuntu 12.04 or 10.04)?

I found this  bug report - bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/543343 on Launchpad. I'm not sure if its fixed yet.

I still face the same errors on Ubuntu 12.04 too.

Comment: This probably has a lot to do with the specific wireless driver and chipset you're using. Do you have another wireless card you can try in your Ubuntu machine to try to rule out configuration issues?

Comment: I tried this among 2 laptops (1 Dell & 1 Lenovo) and 2 Dell desktops. In no case did I succeed.

(Adding the links of tutorials I followed...)